# Unsigned Apache Spark SQL types

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, casting, unsigned

I'm wondering if there are **unsigned** numeric types in Apache Spark SQL?

I don't see any in the [DataType documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html), however, we know that documentation can be partial.

Originally I was trying to cast a very long integer from varchar:

```
SELECT cast(myVeryLongIntAsString as UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

But I got the error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException:
     extraneous input 'INTEGER' expecting ')'
```

According to [MySQL Types documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html), SQL does have an `UNSIGNED INTEGER`.

Answer (score 1):

Spark SQL is not a full SQL engine, but one that provides the main SQL feature.

And no, there is no unsigned type in spark SQL. We can directly look at all defined datatype in the spark source code:
https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types

Sorry :\

Now, is it really necessary? Unsigned SQL type is mostly used to reduce memory size, I think. But in spark, you can use many storage formats. Using signed or unsigned wouldn't really make a difference (compare to choosing binary vs string, or column vs row storage)